# Execute an SQL UPDATE using GROUP BY and COUNT

Tags: sql, sqlite, count, group-by, sql-update

I am working with SQL in an SQLite database. I have a table that looks something like this:

```
STORAGE
------------------------------
REC_ID   SEQ_NO       NAME
------------------------------
100       1          plastic jar
100       2          glass cup
100                  fiber rug
101       1          steel fork
101                  wool scarf
102       1          leather boots
102       2          paintbox
102       3          cast iron pan
102                  toolbox
```

**Keep in mind that that this is a very small number of records compared to what I actually have in the table.** What I need to do is update the table so that all the records that have a null value for SEQ_NO are set with the actual number they are supposed to be in sequence to the group of records with the same REC_ID.

Here is what I want the table to look like after the update:

```
STORAGE
------------------------------
REC_ID   SEQ_NO       NAME
------------------------------
100       1          plastic jar
100       2          glass cup
100       3          fiber rug
101       1          steel fork
101       2          wool scarf
102       1          leather boots
102       2          paintbox
102       3          cast iron pan
102       4          toolbox
```

so for example, the record with REC_ID 102 should have have SEQ_NO of 4, because it is the fourth record with the REC_ID 102.

If I do:

```
SELECT REC_ID, COUNT(*) FROM STORAGE GROUP BY REC_ID;
```

this returns all of the records by REC_ID and the number (count) of records matching each ID, which would also be the number I would want to assign to each of the records with a null SEQ_NO.

Now how would I go about actually updating all of these records with their count values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work:

```
update storage set 
seq_no=(select count(*) from storage s2 where storage.rec_id=s2.rec_id)
where seq_no is null
```

Comment: i got it to work, except I had to switch it around a bit. I first updated the records in the s2 and then inserted them into the s1 table. so I did UPDATE STORAGETWO SET SEQ_NO=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM STORAGE WHERE STORAGE.REC_ID=STORAGETWO.REC_ID);

Comment: yes, that works too, I now removed the alias that was causing problems.